# SharePoint server 2013 Installation Error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, administration

I am getting following error message in my installation.

What would be the reason and how to solve this issue? (OS Windows Server 2012 R2)

> The product requires ASP.NET v4.0 to be in the list of internet information services(IIS) Web Server Extensions.If it is not available in the list,reinstall ASP.NET v4.0

Answer (score 0):

Go on Server Manager and install .Net framework 4.0. check [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/kb/2765375)

It will solve your issue

Recommendation : Install all prerequisite before installing SharePoint

Comment: I Installed ASP.NET 4.5 from server feature.But still i am getting this error.